# jtable how to use rs2xml

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'am currently newbie at java, and I've been searching for a effective way to put database informations to jtable and I heard about rs2xml. I really want to learn this because other methods makes me confuse and gives me headache.

Does anyone know how to use it effectively ? And if you don't mind can you explain with a simple code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to show what you got so far. Also if you hit any particular issues.

Comment: `rs2xml.` - sounds to me like it creates XML, not a JTable. What you really want is something the create a `TableModel` from a `ResultSet`. Check out [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for some ideas. The `TableFromDatabaseExample.java` shows a simple solution.

Comment: rs2xml is a jar library that can be used to make the result set of a query an input for the table model is pretty useful @camickr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;



//..and somewhere in your code
try {
    st = conn.createStatement();
    st.executeQuery(q);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(q);

    // here is where library is used
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); 
    //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
} finally {
    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        /* ignore */ 
    }

    try {
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        /* ignore */ 
    }
}
```

that a sample of use
[video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hg1S3QHFNrE)

Comment: dont forget to implement the jar is needed [adding library tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsS_cRbNv3o)

Answer (score 1):

1. //Before this add rs2XML.jar in your project properties by adding
   //addLibray //option

```
private void b2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    

           int id = 0;
           String name = "";
           String mobile = "";
           String email = ""; 
           String flat = "";
           String query="";


           Connection con;
               try{
                 String query= "select * from apt"
                 con=DBconnect.ConnectDB();//it's a class the connection properties are defined here
                 PreparedStatement ps; 
                 ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                 jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


                    }

           }catch(Exception ee){
               ee.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refrain from code only answers. See :https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Where do you download rs2xml.jar, I can't find it anywhere online